# Invite Friends to my facebook app using " a pop up that will show different friends and a button send "

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, facebook-apps, facebook-app-requests

May i ask on whats wrong with my codes and what suppose to be done to make the whole thing work, as when i click on the hyperlink to test out my code it doesnt seem to work neither does it pop up a page that will display my facebook friends and have the send button for me to send them a notification to my facebook app.i need it to pop up and allow me to select the friends i want and send them the notification

```
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script>
//accepting a request
http://apps.facebook.com/depressionapp/?request_ids=[REQUEST_IDs]


//reading requests
{
request: 'REQUEST_OBJECT_ID'
to:[array of USER_IDs] // what am i suppose to add here also?
} 
</script>
<script>
FB.init({
appId:'445459218940505',
cookie:true,
status:true,
xfbml:true,
oauth  : true,
frictionlessRequests : true
});

function FacebookInviteFriends()
{
FB.ui({
method: 'apprequests',
message: 'Your Message diaolog'
to:{'edmundOHJK'},
action_type:'send',
object_id:''
}, function(response){
console.log(response);
});
}
</script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
if (top.location!= self.location)
{
top.location = self.location
}
</script>


<div id="fb-root"></div>
<a href="#" onclick="FacebookInviteFriends();"> 'Facebook Invite Friends     Link
</a>
</html>
```

Comment: The content of your second `<script>` element isn’t even valid JS code – what gave you the idea it was? And you are aware that you can only use invite requests if your app is actually in the Games category and has a canvas implementation, right?

Comment: so to say, only games category facebook application has a canvas implementation which then allow the code to work?  My facebook app is just a normal facebook application thus, is there any other ways i can do something similar? sorry i am a rookie in coding. @CBroe

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/faq#friend_invite